# Dialog window in Roslyn

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

I would like to implement a Rename-refactoring with Roslyn in Visual Studio. To do this, I want the user to enter the desired name that would be given to selected variable. How can I prompt the user to write the text? Is there a way to display a dialog window with input?

Answer (score 2):

Roslyn doesn't offer it's own specific way to do this.  You would want to create a VS command, and use the `IVsUIShell` to display the dialog.